# Consider adding a browser website to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, feature-request, browser-support

I have a feature request.

You should consider adding a browser Stack Exchange site.

e.g.

- mozilla.stackechange.com

- chrome.stackechange.com

- safari.stackechange.com

Including topics about browser support, browser versions, bugs, etc.

I would like this feature because I use Mozilla Firefox as my browser, I have some bugs some times, and most posts on https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/ are usually around 2-3 years old. I cannot find newer posts (for my browser version).

Comment: [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) is for site proposals.

Comment: Any questions about Chrome, Edge, or Safari are within scope on existing Stack Exchange communities, communities with a ton of users, unlike those communities where there would be only a handful of knowledgeable users. Is there a reason those exist communities cannot answer your questions?

Comment: please no. We don't need sites for individual browsers.

Comment: Or at least add `browsers.stackexchange.com` and post topics about browsers.

Comment: What would browsers.stackexchange.com offer that superuser.com, stackoverflow.com, etc. don't already provide?

Comment: 2 quick notes: first, SE adds sites at their own expense so there must *really* be a good reason. The onus is on the suggesting party to provide reasoning as to why and then gather support and active users, see above comment. Second, we already have a big issue with individual cryptocurrency sites spawn like locust swarms, let's not make it worse.

Comment: @Heretic - It would add absolutely nothing.

Comment: Good on you for taking the plunge to make a suggestion, but you may want to stick around a little longer to get a deeper understanding of what Stack Overflow is first. 24 days is a little on the short side to really take it all in. Of course I make an assumption there, for all i know you've been lurking for years but still.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this isn't the correct place to suggest a site, that's [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

We also already have a sister site on the network for *exactly* these sorts of questions: [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Super User already has *tags* for each of your suggested browser sites, and more:

- [[firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox)]
- [[google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)]
- [[safari](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safari)]
- [[internet-explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)]
- [[opera](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/opera)]

...And the more generic [[browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser)], among several others.

So there's no need to propose a new site– if you're having issues with Firefox, then go ask away on SU! Just make sure to read and abide by [their topical guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) first.